# python kwargs expression evaluation

Tags: python, tkinter, evaluation, keyword-argument

Is there something I should know about passing complex expressions as keyword arguments? The example I'm running into is in tkinter:

```
image = gui.utils.get_image(self.get_icon('pause'), dimensions=(50, 50))
button = ttk.Label(self.mainframe, image=image)
button.place(x=0, y=-10, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

Works, but the following doesn't:

```
button = ttk.Label(self.mainframe, image=gui.utils.get_image(self.get_icon('pause'), dimensions=(50, 50)))
button.place(x=0, y=-10, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

What's the difference? `gui.utils.get_image(self.get_icon('pause'), dimensions=(50, 50))` should be evaluated at the time I pass it to the constructor. Is this a bug in python (I'm on 2.7), or is it somehow tkinter's error? If it helps, I'm running this code in a subthread, but I'm not referencing any objects outside this thread.

Edit:

By "works", I mean the desired image is attached to the background of the label. In the second example, the label appears with the proper size and position, but with a blank background.

Comment: In what way does it not work?  Do you get an error message?  If so, what is the error message?

Comment: Juuust edited my question. See above.

Comment: Can you post a simple but complete runnable example demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the image. [Otherwise, as Fredrik Lundh explains](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm),

> Tkinter tells Tk to release the image. But since the image is in use by
>   a widget, Tk doesn’t destroy it. Not completely. It just blanks the
>   image, making it completely transparent…

Comment: So passing the image in via kwargs doesn't count as keeping a reference? That seems kinda bizarre. By the same logic, wouldn't just passing a hardcoded value as a kwarg be vulnerable to garbage collection?

Comment: Oh, oh, you mean after the image has been applied! What a crazy gotcha

Comment: Right. In your first example, the `image` variable references the image. In the second, you pass the image object to `ttk.Label`, but there is no other reference to the image. So when the `ttk.Label` instance is returned, there are no more references to the image, so Python garage collects the image.

Comment: This behavior should rather be fixed than documented, shouldn't it?

Comment: @moooeeeep: To fix the problem, Tkinter would have to hold on to a reference to every PhotoImage passed to any Tkinter widget. Doing that would subvert the usual process of garbage collection unless the Tkinter user knew where this extra reference was hiding. Tkinter could document *that* behavior, but some might considerer the memory management pitfall to be a bug. So either way, Tkinter would need to require the user to understand this issue.

Comment: Also consider that some code might naturally already hold on to a reference to the image, so PhotoImages would not naturally get garbage collected when one expected unless you manually delete the Tkinter cached reference. That could be annoying....